# Oracle SYSDATE question for datetime column ORA 12899

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, ora-12899

I wrote a trigger in which I have a line:

```
SELECT * 
  INTO :NEW.EVENTDATE 
  FROM (SELECT SYSDATE 
          FROM DUAL);
```

For some reason this does not work (EVENTDATE column has timestamp(0) type).

When I try to insert something I get error message saying that value is too long for that column.  I though SYSDATE and timestamp(0) would coalesce and understand each other.

What the ?

Comment: Can you post the actual DDL of your table?  The error you are getting strongly implies that EventDate is declared as a VARCHAR2, not as a TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Or that the problem is not in the trigger but in the actual INSERT statement.

Answer (score 2):

You should just do this in PL/SQL

```
:new.EventDate := SYSTIMESTAMP;
```

but if you want to use SQL

```
SELECT systimestamp
  INTO :new.EventDate
  FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an explicit cast such as

```
select cast(sysdate as timestamp(0)) from dual
```

As a thought, is there anything exotic with your session's calendar settings which might force a unusual conversion. If so, try specifying the appropriate calendar in a conversion.

```
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-fmMonth-YYYY','nls_calendar=''Arabic Hijrah''') from dual;
```

Comment: Thanx. I actually on my way to learn Oracle built in functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this wouldn't work.  Can you post the actual error (with code and everything) that you are getting?

I also don't know why you wouldn't just assign the variable:

```
:NEW.EVENTDATE := systimestamp;
```

Comment: Because it yields the same error, that actual width 11 is too large for column with width 7!

Answer (score 0):

What version are you running?

The following works fine on Oracle 11R2:

```
drop   table tq84_eventdate;

create table tq84_eventdate (
  data      varchar2(10),
  eventdate timestamp(0)
);

create trigger tq84_eventdate_trg 
before insert on tq84_eventdate 
for each row
begin

  SELECT * INTO :NEW.EVENTDATE FROM (SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL);

end tq84_eventdate_trg;
/


insert into tq84_eventdate (data) values ('test');

select * from tq84_eventdate;
```

However, if I do a

```
insert into tq84_eventdate (data) values ('value too large!');
```

I get the ORA-12899 you mentioned. So, the error is probably not related to the select statement you posted, but to the data that you actually try to insert.

Also, on a related note, you can assign sysdate directly in the trigger, that is without the indirection of a select statement:

```
create trigger tq84_eventdate_trg 
before insert on tq84_eventdate 
for each row
begin

  :new.eventdate := sysdate;

end tq84_eventdate_trg;
/
```

Comment: I'm using 10g.  I can't seem to find a way modify Width property of that column.  It is 7 and that is all to it( I need 11, according to exception

Comment: I don't believe you don't neet 10g. Rather, you need to reduce the length of another value you try to insert.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to exhort my bosses to convert one column's type to another.  Namely timestamp to DATE.

Strangely enough nobody throughout this branch has not pointed out that I could substitute Timestamp field with DATE field.